# Accessing Array Array values

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have a `string[][]` where each entry in the outer array is an array of the lines in a text file.

My question is this, would `string[i][j]` access line i of file j or vice versa?

I have searched for this and haven't been able to find a definitive answer, I'd rather not just use a 2D array as this makes more sense in this context (IMHO).

Thanks!

Comment: Logically, it should be line `j` of file `i`. Think of it this way: `string[i]` will return a `string[]` of lines, of which you want line `j`.

Comment: Surely a simple test with small sample arrays could answer it?

Comment: The first one indexes the outter array and the second the inner array, so without seeing how you populate it I'm guessing it's actually line j of file i.

Comment: Please, have a look at `Dictionary<String, String[]>` where key is a file path and value is the file content; e.g. `myDict[@"C:\MyFile.txt"][5]` - line #6 at `C:\MyFile.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string[i][j]` will access the outer array's content `[i]` and return that array's inner content `[j]`

I'm not sure where the definitive documentation is offhand, but in the time it took you to write the question you could have tested it yourself!

Comment: I realised that as soon as I posted it and was about to post my own answer, thanks for beating me to it though!